# Android JSON Parsing And Conversion

Tags: java, android, json

Good morning.

I am trying to parse `JSON data` into a string but I think I'm doing something wrong: here is the section.

```
private void read_JSON()
    {
    String JSON;
        JSONObject jso3 = new JSONObject(JSON);
        for (int i=0; i < jso3.length(); i++)
        {

        try
        {

            String name = jso3.getString("Nombre");
            String surname = jso3.getString("Apellidos");
            String date = jso3.getString("Año_nacimiento");
            String child_names = jso3.getString("Nombres_Hijos");


        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    jso3.toString(JSON);    
    }
```

I created the JSON **within** the MainActivity.java, it's not on a separate file.

Here is the code of the JSON creation:

```
private void create_JSON()
{
    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jso.put("Nombre","Miguel");
        jso.put("Apellidos", "Garcia");
        jso.put("Año_nacimiento", 1990);
        JSONArray jsa = new JSONArray();
        jsa.put("Blur");
        jsa.put("Clur");
        jso.put("Nombres_Hijos", jsa);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jso.toString();
```

I have no doubts that the `JSON` is correctly created, I just need help in understanding how do I parse it and convert it into a String.

I would be very grateful if you could point out to me the flaws in my programming.

Mauro.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

Your response like below

```
{                             ==> JSONObject
    "Año_nacimiento": 1990,   ==> String from JSONObject
    "Nombres_Hijos": [        ==> JSONArray 
        "Blur",               ==> Directly from JSONArray
        "Clur"
    ],
    "Apellidos": "Garcia",
    "Nombre": "Miguel"
}
```

To **parse** the `JSON` use below code:

```
JSONObject jso3 = new JSONObject(output);
String name = jso3.getString("Nombre");
String surname = jso3.getString("Apellidos");
int date = jso3.getInt("Año_nacimiento");
JSONArray menuObject = jso3.getJSONArray("Nombres_Hijos");
for(int i=0;i<menuObject.length;i++){   
   System.out.println(menuObject.getString(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting errors in all the "get" functions: "The method getString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", "The method getInt(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", "The method getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", and in the .toString function "The method toString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: @user3082271 if your response like my ans `JSON` then ans is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following options while parsing JSON to avoid common error.

```
JSONObject jso3 = new JSONObject(output);
String name = jso3.optString("Nombre",""); // here default value is blank ("")
String surname = jso3.optString("Apellidos",null);// here default value is null
int date = jso3.getInt("Año_nacimiento",0); // here default value is ZERO (0)
JSONArray menuObject = jso3.getJSONArray("Nombres_Hijos");
for(int i=0;i<menuObject.length;i++){   
System.out.println(menuObject.getString(i));
}
```

Using **opt** option you can set default return value. Event if that tag not available in JSON data you will get default value.

This works for me better than GSON lib.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{   

 String JSON ;
        JSONObject jso3 = new JSONObject(JSON);
        JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("array_inside_json"));   
        for(int i=0;i<menuObject.length;i++){   
        name=jObject.getString("inside"));          


        }

}catch(Exception e){

}
```

refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for more info

Comment: Do excuse me, but I'm not sure if I follow... Where do I define the variables "output" and "jObject" in the first place? And how will this code help me parse the JSON into a string? I am sorry, but I'm afraid I don't follow you.

Comment: ouput is the variable storing the  json value from your url connection

Comment: I don't use URLs: the JSON is defined in MainActivity.java, not in a separate file.

Comment: so store  your json from your mainactivity to the variable directly inside the jsonbject.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String apellidos = jso.getString("Apellidos");
System.out.println(apellidos);

int str2 = jso.getInt("Año_nacimiento");
System.out.println(str2);

String nombre = jso.getString("Nombre");
System.out.println(nombre);

JSONArray array = jso.getJSONArray("Nombres_Hijos");
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(array.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting errors in all the "get" functions: "The method getString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", "The method getInt(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", "The method getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", and in the .toString function "The method toString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: As per your JSON creation this is correct code. I am able to parse JSON Object.

Comment: How odd. Maybe I need to close Eclipse and start it up again?

Answer (score 1):

First at all, you seem to ignore Strings created in read_JSON, but i assume you do this to avoid pasting here too much code.

Problem is this line:

```
 String child_names = jso3.getString("Nombres_Hijos");
```

Because fields Nombres_Hijos is JsonArray, not String. To read it use:

```
JSONArray jsa = jso3.getJSONArray("Nombres_Hijos");
```

Now all depands what you need to do later with this data.
Easiest case would be:

```
String names = jsa.toString(); //["Blur","Clur"]
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting errors in all the "get" functions: "The method getString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", "The method getInt(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", "The method getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", and in the .toString function "The method toString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: Show the corrected code on which you get that error.
And best just read more about JSONObject and JSONArray:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: String name = jso3.getString("Nombre"); String surname = jso3.getString("Apellidos"); int date = jso3.getInt("Año_nacimiento");JSONArray jsa2 = jso3.getJSONArray ("Nombres_Hijos");  jso3.toString(json); These are the troublesome spots.

Comment: You are ignoring JSON created in create_JSON - JSON isn't any kind of global container. You should return result String:
return jso.toString();
And then use it as argument: read_JSON(String JSON)

Comment: Then, I need to change the method type from "void" to "string" and then add the "return jso.toString()" instruction?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void read_JSON(String json)
    {

       JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jso3= new JSONArray(jObject.getString("Nombres_Hijos"));   


        for (int i=0; i < jso3.length(); i++)
        {

        try
        {

            String name = jso3.getString("Nombre");
            String surname = jso3.getString("Apellidos");
            String date = jso3.getString("Año_nacimiento");
            String child_names = jso3.getString("Nombres_Hijos");


        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    jso3.toString(JSON);    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting errors in all the "get" functions: "The method getString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", "The method getInt(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", "The method getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)", and in the .toString function "The method toString(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)"